# ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range when using Windows.Media.Devices.FocusControl

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, hololens

I want to use Windows.Media.Devices.FocusControl to manually control the value of focus on HoloLens 2.But when run to the funtion "FocusControl.Configure(FocusSettings)" or "FocusControl.SetValueAsync(UInt32)", it comes with this error.
Here's the offical doucument:[text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/uwp/api/windows.media.devices.focuscontrol?view=winrt-22621)

It's sure that I input the exact supported value and mode because they can be return using the given  properties to get.
On Hololens 2, the min value is 170, while the max is 10000. Whatever value I set, it always comes with this error. Here's the code.

```
if (focusControl.Supported)
{
   await focusControl.LockAsync();
            
   Debug.Log("hhhhhfinsihed");

   //await focusControl.SetValueAsync((uint)focusControl.Min);
   await focusControl.SetValueAsync(focusvalue);
            
   Debug.Log("ohhhhhhhhhhh");
}
```

Also when I use FocusControl.Configure(FocusSettings), it comes with the same error.
Here's the whole code.

```
async private void CaptureImageByMediaCapture()
    {
        MediaCapture mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
        var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
        {
            SharingMode = MediaCaptureSharingMode.SharedReadOnly
        };

        await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);

        var focusControl = mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl;

        var foucussettings = new FocusSettings { Mode = FocusMode.Manual };
        focusControl.Configure(foucussettings);

        Debug.Log(focusControl.Supported);
        if (focusControl.Supported)
        {
            Debug.Log(focusControl.Min);
            Debug.Log(focusControl.Max);
            Debug.Log(focusControl.Step);
            Debug.Log(focusControl.Mode);
            Debug.Log(focusControl.Preset);
            Debug.Log(focusControl.Value);

            await focusControl.LockAsync();
            
            Debug.Log("hhhhhfinsihed");
            await focusControl.SetValueAsync(focusvalue);
            
            Debug.Log("ohhhhhhhhhhh");
            }
            
        }
        else
        {
            ...
        }
..........
```

Without using FocusControl, the code can correctly capture photos on Hololens 2.

Comment: Can you put the output for those ```Debug.Log()```s which show the min, max, preset, step, etc

Comment: True
170
10000
1
Continuous
AutoNormal
0
ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.

Answer (score 1):

For this one, give this sample a look from UWP samples:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/capture-device-controls-for-photo-and-video-capture#focus

```
var focusControl = _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl;

if (focusControl.Supported)
{
    CafFocusRadioButton.Visibility = focusControl.SupportedFocusModes.Contains(FocusMode.Continuous) 
        ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
}
else
{
    CafFocusRadioButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried out this answer but there could be a problem with the following code line:

```
var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
{
    SharingMode = MediaCaptureSharingMode.SharedReadOnly
};
```

This enum has the following definition in Microsoft documentation:

### Fields

ExclusiveControl    0
The MediaCapture should have exclusive control of one or more of the frame sources specified in SourceGroup.

SharedReadOnly  1
The MediaCapture can acquire frames from the frame sources specified in SourceGroup but can't adjust the configuration of the frame sources.

Maybe you should try with `ExclusiceControl`

```
var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
{
    SharingMode = MediaCaptureSharingMode.ExclusiveControl
};
```

Also, you might need to check if manual focus is supported:

```
if (focusControl.SupportedFocusModes.Contains(FocusMode.Manual))
{
    // Manual focus is supported
}
```

Also, you could try checking the supported focus ranges with:

```
focusControl.SupportedFocusRanges;
```

Comment: supported modes and ranges have been checked which contains Manual. While changing to ExclusiveControl still can't solve the problem.